# How output a full name that starts with last name? What if the the first name or last name consist of words?

Tags: c++

i need some help (C++)

Make a program that will input the full name once but output of full name will start with last name.

I attached my code but this code will read only the first word of first name or first word of last name. What if the first name or last name has two words? Thank you.

```
<pre>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

main()
{
   string first, middle, last;
   cout << "What is your full name? ";
   cout << endl << "---> ";
   cin >> first >> middle >> last;

   cout << "---> " << last << ", " << first << " " << middle;
   cout << endl;

   return 0;



 }
<code>
```

[full name program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dZfB.jpg)

Comment: Post code as text, not an image. Much harder to copy it as an image.

Comment: [Read full lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead?

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "What if the first name or last name has two words?" How do you intend to distinguish whether the first name _or_ the last name consists of two words? In other words: If you get three names - is it two words for last name or two words for first name?

Comment: So the question is, how do you know what the first and last names are if they are multiple words? If I input "John Jacob Jingleheimer Smith" Is the last name "Smith" or "Jingleheimer Smith"? Is the first name "John" or "John Jacob"? There's no way of knowing. You need what's called a delimiter to separate the two.

Comment: May be, your code gives a hint but I cannot see the image. (Sorry, company security policy prevents any access to imgur.com.) A possible solution for the last name/first name topic would be to use a comma (`,`) for separation. This might even be optional (with some fall-back "strategy" if it is missing).

Comment: You're probably expected to assume that everyone has exactly one of each. (You're already assuming that everyone has one first name, one middle name, and one last name, which isn't necessarily true. See also [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you mean, from an example name :

"first middle middle2 ... middle-n last"

you would like to output

"last, first middle .... middle-n".

To do this, you can..

- **Use `std::getline(cin, name)` to get the name.**

Using `cin >> name` will truncates the string when it meets a whitespace `" "`. Which means only get the first "word" before whitespace.

To avoid this, use `getline`.

- **Use `string::find_last_of(" ")`**
- **Use `string::substr(pos, span)` to get the desired substring.**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

---

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string> 
    using namespace std; 
    int main() { 
        string name, last; 
        cout << "What is your full name? "; 
        cout << endl << "---> "; 
        getline(cin,name);
        int idx;
        idx = name.find_last_of(" ");
        cout << idx << endl;
        last = name.substr(idx+1);
        cout << "---> " << last << ", " << name.substr(0, idx);
         cout << endl; return 0; }
```

Example output :

```
What is your full name :
---> first middle middle2 middle3 last
28
---> last, first middle middle2 middle3
```

Answer (score 0):

The input stream will be in a failure state if the read fails (i.e. no word was read).  So, the solution is to test the stream state after each read.

```
if (cin >> first)
{
  if (cin >> middle)
  {
    if (cin >> last)
    {
      //...
    }
    else
    {
      last = middle;
    }
  }
}
```

You should test each name and output only if it is not empty.